# Vimium - how to map vimium shortcut keys over chrome default shortcut keys?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, vimium

I installed [Vimium](http://vimium.github.io/) for my Chrome browser to use but I noticed that Chrome shortcut keys take higher priority. 
For instance, if I try `<C-u>`, instead of scrolling a page up, I see the source code of the page.

How can I configure Chrome or Vimium to use Vimium shortcuts rather than built-in Chrome shortcuts?

Comment: You should not have `<` and `>` directly inside a text of an answer, either escape them as `&lt;` and `&gt;`, or put inside a backticks. And don't forget to use a preview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You currently cannot map any default Chrome shortcut keys defined already. That is unfortunately one limitation of Google Chrome Extensions API. The Extension team is familiar with such restrictions, and they have it on their queue for future APIs.

In the meantime, try to pick a shortcut that doesn't conflict.

Hope that kinda helped.

Comment: This is why I stick to FF + {vimperator,pentadactyl}

Comment: Chrome is young and fresh! The main focus for chrome (my opinion) is Speed, Security, Stability. Extensions has been released this year, and more APIs are being exposed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually David's answer should work somehow. Some may misunderstood, these commands are added in Vimium's Options Settings.

By the way, if you want to add  and  as scrolling full page up and down, just add the following in the "Custom Key Mapping":

```
unmap <c-f>
map <c-f> scrollFullPageDown
unmap <c-b>
map <c-b> scrollFullPageUp
```

This works for me. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

First unmap the previous shortcut,

```
unmap <C-u>
map <C-u> scrollPageDown
```

Comment: Huh? This is Vimium. There are no map/unmap.